# Ultimate beginner's tutorial to 3d game dev using XNA Framework?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm looking for a tutorial that starts at square 1 for game development and moves up through intermediate/expert levels of 3D game development. I really want to get into 3D game dev and I've been trying to for awhile in my free time, but I know so little at times that I'm not even sure what terminology to use in order to phrase a question properly.

Ideally, I'm hoping to find tutorials for the XNA Framework, what little experience I have is XNA.

I've been developing for years and don't really need help with the language. What I know I need help on is stuff like rendering, what exactly a Matrix represents, and other things in the framework's library. I don't even know what all is available in the library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) is pretty decent, actually. I assume you've got a decent understanding of gamedev in general (else you're kind of stuck).

A book which I think is pretty good is [Learning XNA 4.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449394620). It starts off with 2D stuff for the first few chapters, but quickly progresses into 3D - cameras, models, shaders, et al. It's not much of a tutorial to making a game to a decent overview of XNA, 3D in light detail, and knowing the useful things.

As for the framework itself, it isn't **that** difficult to just pick it up as you go along. Pick a simple game to try for and search out what you need (of course, the book is really good for this).